# Appsettings values not being read running EF migration in Devops build pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines

When running a command line task in a Devops build pipeline to create an EF migration SQL script, the values from AppSettings.json (and the `IConfigurationSection` derived from them) are not populated. They are always null.

This is an issue as there are several configuration classes which are instantiated and used within the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method of this .Net Core 3.1 project.

The `eg migration script` command line works fine when running locally, but not when executed as part of the build pipeline. Are there any configuration steps within devops I can take to ensure that the appsettings.json file is read and successfully loaded within the `ConfigureServices()` call? Is there a step which is being missed?

For reference this is the Devops task:

```text
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "Build EF Migrations"
  inputs:
    script: |
      dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
      dotnet ef migrations script -p ProjectName.Domain -s ProjectName.API -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\migrations\scripts.sql -i -v
```

This is the simplified version of the `ConfigureServices()` logic:

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // Issue: all properties in the below classes are always null
  var jwtConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("Jwt").Get<JwtConfiguration>();
  var storageConfiguration = Configuration.GetSection("Storage").Get<StorageConfiguration>();

  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(storageConfiguration.Sql.ConnectionString));
  services.ConfigureJwt(jwtConfiguration);

  // other configuration settings...
}
```

Finally, these are the errors as taken from the verbose output of the EF command in the Devops task:

```text
System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. (Parameter 's')  
 at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)  
 at Project.API.StartupExtensions.ConfigureJwt(IServiceCollection services, JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration) in D:\a\1\s\PatientGo.API\Startup.Jwt.cs:line 22  
 at Project.API.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\a\1\s\PatientGo.API\Startup.cs:line 46  

System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'PatientGo.Domain.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
```

Line 22 of Startup.Jwt.cs is the first time in the code where a member of the `JwtConfiguration` class is accessed.

The latter error is because `storageConfiguration.Sql.ConnectionString` is `null` when it should be filled with the connection string from appsettings.json

Comment: This is a configuration error that has nothing to do with EF Core. What does `ConfigureJwt` do? Does the `appsettings.json` file exist on the build server? Are there any environment-specific files or settings that override it, or whatever settings are used by `ConfigureJwt`? If you search SO for `ef migrations configuration` or `appsettings` you'll find several related answers anyway, including how to use different appsettings per environment during migrations. [As the docs explain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) `migrations` does use conf

Comment: What does your code do? What's the *actual* full exception text?  Does your `ConfigureJwt` method try to instantiate a DbContext from `services`? Trying to configure Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL perhaps? Which EF Core version are you using? Recent versions have made Azure authentication a *lot* easier

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you have two options:

Create no parameter constructor in your ApplicationDbContext and use [OnConfiguring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#onconfiguring) method to pass options:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test");
    }
}
```

Implement [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) interface and tell how to instantiate your context. What is funny that I see in my project even connection string is wrong is still is able to generate scripts in Azure DevOps. So it will try to connect to database only when you run command to generate migration. Also i think if you do this way you wont need to pass `-s ProjectName.API`

```
public class ApplicationContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=(local);database=your_db;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");

            return new ApplicationDbContext (optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

In my case this works in Azure devOps and it does not complain

PS: As  Panagiotis Kanavos pointed dont hardcode those values my answer is just pointing you to how you can fix :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `During migration it does not need to instantiate your application. So ConfigureServices wont run.` This doesn't appear to be the case. `ConfigureServices` is running as the error (taken from the verbose output of the Devops task specifically points to the line in startup which references the `jwtConfiguration` accessor. I've updated the question to include the error.

Comment: With regards to your comment on having 2 steps, 1 to create the SQL script in the build pipeline and 1 to run the script in the release pipeline - this is exactly what I'm attempting to recreate. It's the generation of the SQL script in the build pipeline which is causing the error in my question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated my answer. Hope it make sense :)

Comment: The answer is wrong. Hard-coding a connection string won't fix the errors thrown by the configuration methods as execution hasn't reached the DbContext yet. This wouldn't help even if it did, if the actual connection string was different. Migrations *do* use the configuration middleware. There are several SO questions about this, including questions about loading different files per environment etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have you read links I attached?

Comment: @VovaBilyachat read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) that explain migrations use the configuration middleware. Again, the error wasn't raised by the DbContext. The exception was thrown by the `Startup` code, long before any DbContexts were created or even registered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos have you read in that docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you please read section "From a design-time factory"